# How to run a powershell script with admin rights by double clicking it

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run a powershell script that disables my touch screen. I want to just double click it and have it run.

I've tried adding this to the **Target** in the shortcut I created of the original .ps1:

`powershell.exe -f "C:\Users\OnionMan\Desktop\Disable Touchscreen.ps1"` and clicking on run as administrator

and I've tried the bottom Target shortcut as well

`C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File "C:\Users\OnionMan\Desktop\Disable Touchscreen.ps1"`

Here's the command to turn off the touch screen(if someone knows a way to toggle it on and off with the same script that would be nice!)

`Get-PnpDevice | Where-Object {$_.FriendlyName -like '*touch screen*'} | Disable-PnpDevice -Confirm:$false`

Comment: PS is associated with Notepad. They are by default not designed/implemented to be run using double click. If you want this, you create a .bat/.cmd file (for a double-click) and then call the .ps1 file from the bat. You can change this (the extension association) on your system, but that is ill-advised, and you are opening yourself to unnecessary risks. You can also just create a point in your SendTO folder for right-click run actions.

Comment: Usually `-Verb RunAs` to elevate. You could scheduled it with Task Scheduler and running as `nt authority\system` and then have another PowerShell script to using 
`Start-ScheduledTask "Job Disable TouchPad";` that runs a `.cmd` batch file running the logic it the script it points to as just `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File "C:\Users\OnionMan\Desktop\Disable Touchscreen.ps1`. THis should work for your need given you run that as system or some explicit credential with admin access on it.